# How to resize a table when the rows decrease?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a table under a searchbar. When I write something inside it, it filters that word with my skills list and the table appears bottom the bar.

Everything works well but not the size of this div because it have an height of 300px so if I have 10 skills is ok, but if the skill are, for example, 2, every td will have a height of 150px.

So I would like to fix this with a max height of 300px and when the rows decrease I want the table to get smaller.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <ng-container
            *ngIf="searchString.searchString && (searchSkills.getAllSkill() | filterAll : searchString.searchString) as filteredSkills">
        <ng-container *ngIf="filteredSkills.length > 0">
            <div class="suggerite">
                <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize]="10" class="sugtab style-bar modal-bar">
                    <table class="sugtab">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr *cdkVirtualFor="let skill of filteredSkills" class="sugtag">
                            <td (click)="addToSearch(skill)" class="skill">
                                {{skill.name}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.suggerite{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #064a94;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    color: #064a94;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}

.sugtab{
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

tr.sugtab {
    height: 50px;
}

td.skill{
    padding: 3px;
}
```

I tried to use max height and different things but probably in wrong places.

Comment: did u try height :auto;

Comment: basically if u give a elements height in css it will be on that particular height only!
doest matter what it has

Comment: @madhavsaibhushan I tried auto and it doesn't appear, I know about the height, it was a temporary solution. I already finisci this project, this is 1 of 3 to do, so I would appreciate any suggestion :)

Comment: can you re-create this in a stackblitz ?

Comment: @dince12 [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j7kkcl)
It's not perfect but I tried to explain you what I would like in comments, thanks in advance!